# Two elements but only one inserted into database (even in a loop)

Tags: php, sql

```
     for ($i = 0; $i < count($cart); $i++) {
                $proid = $cart[$i]["proid"]; //1
                $prodName = $cart[$i]["prod_name"]; //2
                $price = $cart[$i]["unit_price"]; //3
                $taken = $cart[$i]["taken"]; //4
                if ($cart[$i]['taken'] > 0) {
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO `tblchitiethoadon`(`Ma_HD`, `Ma_SP`, `Ten_SP`, `SoLuong`, `Gia`)";
                    $sql.="  VALUES ({$mahd},{$proid},'{$prodName}',{$taken},{$price})";
                    $result = mysql_query($sql);
/* $mahd i got it before */
                }
            }
```

I got 3 elements in array $cart,2 of them got `cart[$i]['taken'] > 0` (i also echo `$cart with $cart[$i]['taken'] > 0` condition for sure ) but in the database i just got the first and only one element.

Comment: Take out the dot on `$sql.=`

Comment: @JeremyMiller nope that would break it further

Comment: That's wrong -- it's needed to concatenate the two parts of the query.

Comment: Oh, duh!  I guess I shouldn't reply when I'm tired, lol.

Comment: Nothing wrong with code you have posted check with `or die(mysql_error())` are you getting any error or not ?

Comment: Use `mysql_real_escape_string` to escape your values, which will protect you from SQL injection and may solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Typo/Syntax Error**

```
$sql.="  VALUES ({$mahd},{$proid},'{$prodName}',{$taken},{$price})";
```

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^(semicolon missing)

**correct:**

```
$sql.="  VALUES ({$mahd},{$proid},'{$prodName}',{$taken},{$price});";
```

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^

**Reason:**

Since you are using for loop to form the query.your query will look like

insert into table1(a,b,c) values(1,1,1)insert into table1(a,b,c) values(2,3,4)
**which is wrong syntactically**.

[see here](http://3v4l.org/9aY3U)

*you can echo your $sql and run it in phpmyadmin*

**Better Approach:**

The better approach to your code(it will reduce the unwanted overhead,form the string inside the loop and execute it outside the loop):

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO `tblchitiethoadon`
        (`Ma_HD`, `Ma_SP`, `Ten_SP`, `SoLuong`, `Gia`)   VALUES";

 for ($i = 0; $i < count($cart); $i++) {
                $proid = $cart[$i]["proid"]; //1
                $prodName = $cart[$i]["prod_name"]; //2
                $price = $cart[$i]["unit_price"]; //3
                $taken = $cart[$i]["taken"]; //4
                if ($cart[$i]['taken'] > 0) {

               $sql11.="   ({$mahd},{$proid},'{$prodName}',{$taken},{$price}),";


                }
            } 
 $sql=$sql1.$sql11;
 $sql=trim($sql,",");//to remove the extra semicolon at the end of the string.
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
```

**Please Dont use mysql_* as these are depracated and you are prone to sql injections.**

Answer (score 0):

Loop will execute count($cart) times and the insertion action will occure if `($cart[$i]['taken'] > 0)` is true.Make sure the condition is true for each time.

Answer (score -2):

Try these this coding:

```
               $sql = "INSERT INTO tblchitiethoadon (Ma_HD, Ma_SP, Ten_SP, SoLuong,  Gia) VALUES ('$mahd','$proid','$prodName','$taken','$price')";

               $result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: your code is correct but this is not what OP wants.Op is using for loop to concatenate his query string.

Comment: and downvote means "your answer is not useful" not "your code is wrong"